# EDSDK 2.13. Get the reference of the camera that took the picture when receiving a new picture on the computer

Tags: c#, .net, camera, edsdk, canon-sdk

I can't find any solutions on the internet for my issue. It must be because it's a really specific question.
I have multiple cameras connected to my laptop and I can shoot simultaneously and get all the pictures taken and save them to a directory on my computer. 
This part is working great. But now, I need to rename my pictures using the serial number of the camera which took the shot. The problem is I can't find out how to retrieve any informations on my camera when downloading the pictures. The EdsObjectEventHandler doesn't give me the camera reference.

If one of you found a way to do this I'll be pleased to know. I'll keep on searching.

Thanks

Mat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I searched for a moment today and found that when using EDSDK.EdsSetObjectEventHandler, we can pass an inContext parameter at the end:

```
public extern static uint EdsSetObjectEventHandler( IntPtr  inCameraRef, uint inEvnet,
         EdsObjectEventHandler  inObjectEventHandler, IntPtr inContext );
```

This parameter is whatever we want to pass when the event will be raised, so we can pass our camera reference (its pointer) and use it when we the event is trigger to download the picture and rename it using properties of our shooting camera.

I don't know if I'm clear but if you have questions don't bother asking.